# External drive EFI bootloader with Debian 7.7 Wheezy

Tags: debian, lvm, uefi

I'm currently trying to install Debian 7.7 on a removable drive with an encrypted LVM from DVD-1 with a self contained EFI bootloader like the one the DVD uses - that is, the computer's HDD should be untouched, and any EFI computer that's booted with the drive should be able to load it. Half of the time, however, the bootloader seems to ignore me telling it not to use the HDD's EFI partition, and while the installation boots the native Windows install fails to boot without the drive.

The other half of the time GRUB2 outright fails to install - an attempt to install GRUB2 from the disc's rescue mode resulted in an error stating that the EFI partition didn't look right, so I deleted and remade it (FAT32 with the correct label). GRUB2 then installs, but the disk only boots to a GRUB terminal with the drive.

Specifically, how do I get Debian Wheezy to install to a layout like this? The particular issues I'm having here are specifying a different device for the EFI bootloader and not knowing what partitions need to be outside encryption for an EFI boot to work.